# Multiple forms on a single page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actionview

I've got an app that's in invite-only beta right now. Problem is, I can't get the invite system to work. :(

On my root page there's a login form (which works just fine), and I'm trying to add a "request invite" form on the same page. I started doing it by putting the form for InviteRequest (ActiveRecord) inside a partial, in the "views" folder for "InviteRequest". The app is definitely calling this partial, but I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in User_sessions#new

Showing app/views/invite_request/_new.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `invite_requests_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x25b3248>
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <% @invite_request = InviteRequest.new() %>
2: <% form_for @invite_request do |ir| %>
3:  <%= ir.label :email %>
4:  <%= ir.text_field :email %>
5: <% end %>
```

I also read through the "Multiple Models in a Form" section of my trusty copy of ["Agile Web Development with Rails"](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition), about maybe doing this with a "fieldset" tag, but not sure if this is the right approach.

Thx.

Comment: In case this is relevant, this partial is being called from the "user_session" controller, "new" action page (i.e. the login page). So, I could also have some kind of scope issue.

Comment: *I might also* just put the "request invite" functionality on its own page, which would be simpler, but it'd be nice if it wasn't an extra click away. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `form_for @invite_request` is trying to figure out where the results from the form should be posted. It does this by looking at the routes and finding one that matches the resource and action needed. In your case I'm guessing you haven't set up routes for `InviteRequest`. You either need to set up routing for `InviteRequest` or specify the URL to be posted to in `form_for`.

```
form_for @invite_request, :url => { :controller => 'application', :action => 'request_invite' } do |form|
  ...
```

Comment: Yikes, that was so simple. Thank you!

I did have "map.resources invite_request" in my routes.rb file, and I'd restarted mongrel after the change before I posted the question. But obviously I was missing something in the routing/url mapping.

So, I used the specified ":url => ..." you suggested. Rock on. Thanks.