# Multiple form components within a single form in CQ5.6/5.5

Tags: forms, validation, aem

I need to create a form on my page which would accept values from the end user, validate the input (basic stuff, nothing fancy, to check whether required fields are filled etc.) along with a captcha to eliminate spam bots.

Currently, I have a standalone **reCaptcha** component set up for my form. It works fine on it's own. I was thinking along the lines of adding this along with any of the out of the box form components that CQ5 provides (the **address** component caught my fancy).

The problem arises with the validation. When I click submit, the validations for the **address** component never seem to execute. Which leads me to my question.

i) Is it allowed for me to continue with my current methodology (i.e 1 main **form** component which contains one **reCaptcha** component and one **address** component)? If I can, how can I map the validations accurately for the entire form to behave as I want when I hit submit. (I would need the **address** form to check for required fields, the **reCaptcha** to check if the challenge field is valid, **in that order**)

ii) If I cannot carry out the task in this way, would I have to create an entirely new component for my form, one which includes the code for both the **address** component and the **reCaptcha** component and include both their validations within 1 file? Logically, I can see the merit of this approach, it does seem much easier. But I would like to maintain the **reCaptcha** component as a stand alone, to effect reusability across my site.

A similar topic does exist on how to handle [Multiple forms on a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443187/multiple-forms-on-a-single-page), but since it involves Ruby, which I have next to zero knowledge on, I couldn't really implement.

I'd appreciate it if I could get some information on how to achieve this in context to CQ5.

Thanks
(apologies for the really long wall of text)

Comment: A CQ form can contain multiple form fields, so have you actually tried to provide your captcha as form field component and add it to the same form as the address component? Then you can have field-level and form-global constraints. [See also official Adobe docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/developing-forms.html).

Comment: How are you handling the validation for reCaptcha?

Comment: @Woodifer i have a separate reCaptcha component, which consists of 2 .jsp files; one for display and one for validation.

Comment: I have a working recaptcha component that can be used in mutltiple forms on a single page.  I built it in an OSGi bundle instead of doing it clientside.  I can post some code up if you think it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after tinkering about with my form for a while, I was eventually able to get it to work!

So, yes it is indeed possible to have a multiple form components within a single form. The issue with validations can be sorted out by taking a look at how the validations are managed for any of the OOTB form field components individually.

To clarify, the OOTB Captcha component uses the ***Layout.printError()*** method to display any issues with validation. I sorta reworked this into my Recaptcha component, and made the necessary changes into the servervalidation.jsp. Worked fine!

And with respect to the 2nd point in the question, I'd suggest not going down that road as I feel it's always better if my component is stand alone.